# using comma separated values inside IN clause for NUMBER column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have 2 procedures inside a package. I am calling one procedure to get a comma separated list of user ids.

I am storing the result in a `VARCHAR` variable. Now when I am using this comma separated list to put inside an `IN` clause in it is throwing "`ORA-01722:INVALID NUMBER"` exception.

This is how my variable looks like

```
l_userIds VARCHAR2(4000) := null;
```

This is where i am assigning the value

```
l_userIds := getUserIds(deptId);  -- this returns a comma separated list
```

And my second query is like -

```
select * from users_Table where user_id in (l_userIds);
```

If I run this query I get `INVALID NUMBER` error.

Can someone help here.

Comment: the query is incomplete, the select by itself is not plsql (you need to store the resultset into a variable) please show the complete query

Comment: try this select * from users_Table where user_id in (select l_userIds);

Answer (score 8):

Do you really need to return a comma-separated list?  It would generally be much better to declare a collection type

```
CREATE TYPE num_table
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Declare a function that returns an instance of this collection

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_nums
  RETURN num_table
IS
  l_nums num_table := num_table();
BEGIN
  for i in 1 .. 10
  loop
    l_nums.extend;
    l_nums(i) := i*2;
  end loop;
END;
```

and then use that collection in your query

```
SELECT *
  FROM users_table
 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE( l_nums ));
```

It is possible to use dynamic SQL as well (which @Sebas demonstrates).  The downside to that, however, is that every call to the procedure will generate a new SQL statement that needs to be parsed again before it is executed.  It also puts pressure on the library cache which can cause Oracle to purge lots of other reusable SQL statements which can create lots of other performance problems.

Comment: Does the limit of 1000 values in an IN clause apply when using a collection/table in this manner?  Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis - No, it doesn't.  The 1000 value limit only applies to literals or individual bind variables, not queries (whether against tables or collections).

Comment: Hi @JustinCave just tried this , Believe two corrections required `return l_nums; ` inside function  and while using collection in query - `...select * from TABLE(get_nums)`

Answer (score 3):

You can search the list using `like` instead of `in`:

```
select *
from users_Table
where ','||l_userIds||',' like '%,'||cast(user_id as varchar2(255))||',%';
```

This has the virtue of simplicity (no additional functions or dynamic SQL).  However, it does preclude the use of indexes on `user_id`.  For a smallish table this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that oracle does not interprete the VARCHAR2 string you're passing as a sequence of numbers, it is just a string.

A solution is to make the whole query a string (VARCHAR2) and then execute it so the engine knows he has to translate the content:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE T_UT IS TABLE OF users_Table%ROWTYPE;
    aVar T_UT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from users_Table where user_id in (' || l_userIds || ')' INTO aVar;
...

END;
```

A more complex but also elegant solution would be to split the string into a table TYPE and use it casted directly into the query. See what [Tom thinks about it](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061).

Comment: This is weird, I have string column and i do `IN` clause in a list of comma separated string stored in a variable and oracle doesn't interpret it as sequence of string. But when i do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` it works. Why oracle  doesn't  interpret even sequence of string to do filter on string column ?

Answer (score -1):

**DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION!**

Firstly, I wanted to delete it, but I think, it might be informative for someone to see such a bad solution. Using dynamic SQL like this causes multiple execution plans creation - 1 execution plan per 1 set of data in IN clause, because there is no binding used and for the DB, every query is a different one (SGA gets filled with lots of very similar execution plans, every time the query is run with a different parameter, more memory is needlessly used in SGA).

Wanted to write another answer using Dynamic SQL more properly (with binding variables), but **[Justin Cave's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006971/3364457)** answer is the best, anyway.

<strike>You might also wanna try REF CURSOR (haven't tried that exact code myself, might need some little tweaks):</strike>

```
DECLARE
    deptId                  NUMBER := 2;
    l_userIds               VARCHAR2(2000) := getUserIds(deptId);
    TYPE t_my_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
    c_cursor                t_my_ref_cursor;
    l_row                   users_Table%ROWTYPE;
    l_query                 VARCHAR2(5000);
BEGIN
    l_query := 'SELECT * FROM users_Table WHERE user_id IN ('|| l_userIds ||')';
    OPEN c_cursor FOR l_query;

    FETCH c_cursor INTO l_row;
    WHILE c_cursor%FOUND
    LOOP
        -- do something with your row
        FETCH c_cursor INTO l_row;
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Doing dynamic SQL like this works (and that's what @Sebas suggested a couple years ago).  But you're generating distinct, non-sharable SQL statements that will put a lot of pressure on your shared pool.  If you're going to run this code frequently, you're going to create performance issues for your system.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Indeed, inding dynamic SQL is way better regarding performance.